# xmlhttp from variable rather than url - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I am pulling in multiple xml files that are stored in the var names from a loop, but I want to use the xmlhttp request with the variable names, since it changes each iteration rather than reassigning the path every time i.e. folder/file.xml. So Basically I need help using the xmlhttp request to pull in xml details with a variable rather than a direct link i.e.:

I have:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","FileNames.xml",false);
```

But I need:

```
var names = "xmlf/file.xml";
xmlhttp.open("GET",names,false);
```

EDIT:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","FileNames.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FileNames");
document.write("<tr>");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 

  document.write("<td>");
  var names = (x[i].getElementsByTagName("File")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
 // document.write(names);
```

my var names changes with each loop iteration, how can I store it like var names = [names[i],names[i], to x.length]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have this right, you can do the following:

```
var names = [];
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
    document.write("<td>");
    names.push(x[i].getElementsByTagName("File")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    // your remaining code here
}
```

Note `names.push`, which lets you add an element to the `names` array.

Now, with all the names stored, you can loop through and do your XML requests on them:

```
for (var n = 0; n < names.length; n++) {
    xmlhttp.open("GET", names[n], false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    // act on XML response here
}
```

Comment: I edited my original post with updated code, your answer doesn't really apply because I can't specify var names = ["a.xml", "b.xml", ...] because I am looping through a variable of unknown size

Comment: If you have multiple `<File>` tags in each `<FileNames>` tag, you'll need to add a subloop in place of the names.push line: `for (var j = 0; j < x[i].getElementsByTagName("File").length; j++) { names.push(x[i].getElementsByTagName("File")[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue); }`